# stl c++: class in a set

Tags: c++, class, stl, set

I can put a class in a set ?  as this case todos.insert(a)

```
  class arco {
     public:
        arco(int x0, int y0, int z0, int x1, int y1, int z1);
     private:
        std::vector<int> a;
        std::vector<int> b;
        std::set< std::vector<int> > vertices;
  };  
  class arcos {
     public:
        arcos();
        void setArco(arco a); 
     private:
        std::set<arco> todos; 
  };  


  arco::arco(int x0, int y0, int z0, int x1, int y1, int z1){
     std::vector<int> a(3);
     std::vector<int> b(3);
     a[0]=x0;
     a[1]=y0;
     a[2]=z0;
     b[0]=x1;
     b[1]=y1;
     b[2]=z1;
     vertices.insert(a);
     vertices.insert(b);
  }   
  void arcos::setArco(arco a){ 
     todos.insert(a);
  }
```

Comment: What is the question here?  Its not entirely clear.

Comment: @Mark:  I just went with the stated literal question, "I can put a class in a set ?"

Comment: @John: Yea, I was hoping for something a bit more specific since that seemed way too general :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just overload `operator<` for `class arco` or use some comparator

EDIT: 
One way:

```
struct compare_arcos
{
  bool operator()( const arco& a1, const arco& a2 ) const
  {
    //..
  }
};
```

Or

```
  bool operator<( const arco& a1, const arco& a2 ) const
  {
    //..
  }
```

If you choose the first way, you sould pass `compare_arcos` as an argument of the `set`

---

Uh, this `arcos::arcos(){std::set<arco> todos;}` is completely useless.. and wrong

Comment: yeah, I guess he wanted to make `todos` as a private member and instead sticked it in constructor

Comment: @Gene - actually, it is private, this in the constructor will shadow the member, i think

Comment: if I put 
      bool arco::operator<(const arco& a1, const arco& a2) const {
         return true;
      }   
I get this error

error: ‘bool cube::core::arco::operator<(const cube::core::arco&, const cube::core::arco&) const’ must take exactly one argument

Comment: @JuanPablo - yes, this is normal, because of the "hidden" `this` parameter. `operator<` should be outside the class, if you use it with 2 arguments. If you want it to be inside the class (as a method, member function) use it with only one argument and compare it with `this` object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define strict weak ordering for your type in order to instantiate `set` on it. It can be an `operator<` or a functor.

Edit and clarification. The `set` declaration is this:

```
template <
   class Key, 
   class Traits=less<Key>, 
   class Allocator=allocator<Key> 
>
class set;
```

`Key` is your type, `Traits` should be your comparison function, or if you define `operator<` you can keep default `less<Key>` you can keep default `allocator`.

Comment: You can also just specialize less<> for your class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with caveats.

For all STL containers, contained objects are required to be:

- Copy constructible.  You can accomplish this by providing a copy constructor
- Assignable.  You can accomplish this with an assignment operartor `operator=(const MyObject&)`

In addition, for associative containers, contained objects must be strict-weak comparable.  The set itself defines the default implementation of this comparison using `less<key_type>`, but you can define your own if you wish.

You will often use the default `less<key_type>` comparison.  When you do so, you must provide an `bool operator<` on your object.  There are other, more cumbersome ways to fulfil the strict-weak comparable requirement that do not require you to provide an `operator<` on your class.